# Name 'absolute value' not defined in Python

Tags: python, spyder, absolute, defined

So I am really knew to coding, this is problem occurred about 5 minutes after I started. So I am currently doing this Coursera course made by an associate professor at Wesleyan (https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-programming-introduction). One of the exercises was:

Write a function `absolutevalue(num)` that computes the absolute value of
a number. You will need to use an 'if' statement. Remember if a number is less than zero then you must multiply by -1 to make it greater than zero.

So I figured my answer should be something like this:

```
absolutevalue(num):
    
""" Computes the absolute value of a number."""
    
if num >> 0:
        
absolutevalue =num
        
print(absolute value)
    
elif num<< 0:
        
absolutevalue == -1*num
        
print(absolutevalue)
    
else:
        
print("Absolute value is 0")
```

But when I run the code the console keeps saying:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
> absolutevalue(5)
>
> NameError: name 'absolutevalue' is not defined

For the past hour, I have been trying to fix the problem, yet I don't know how.

Could someone please help me, and keep in mind this is one of my first times trying to code something.
Thanks

Comment: greater than should be `>` not `>>`....same with less than `<` not `<<`. Functions need `def` in front of the function name. And remember to indent properly

Comment: and, assign with `=` not `==`

Answer (score 2):

A few errors:

Your `def` statement is missing. Normally a function definition should start with a line like `def absolutevalue(num)` rather than just `absolutevalue(num)`.

You're using double comparators `>>` where you should be using single ones `>`. The former is a bit-shifting operator.

Within the function, you're using a variable with the same name as the function itself: `absolutevalue`. It's not necessarily wrong, but definitely not particularly handy.

Your function doesn't actually return the absolute value; it just prints it.

Edit: now that your question has been edited to use code blocks: your indentation is missing. :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Also, a space in `print(absolute value)`. But none of those really explain the error OP is getting. Probably defined that function in a file he is never importing.

Comment: @tobias You are correct! I was thinking that `absolutevalue` wasn't defined because of the missing `def`, but now that I consider it, that should actually result in a `SyntaxError`!

Comment: Yeah thanks! However, now this turns up when i run the code: n [10]: absolutevalue(5)
absolutevalue(-5)
absolutevalue(4-4)

 absolute value is num 
<function absolutevalue at 0x112a70d90>
Absolute value is 0

Answer (score 1):

Function definitions in python need to start with `def`. Function blocks also need to be indented correctly, for example:

```
def absolutevalue(num):
    """ Computes the absolute value of a number."""

    if num > 0:
        return num
    elif num < 0:
        return -1 * num
    return 0

print(absolutenumber(-1))
print(absolutenumber(1))
print(absolutenumber(0))

>>> 1
>>> 1
>>> 0
```

Comment: Thank you! Going to start another course next week. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the function absolutevalue and pass num into it.  If you need to return the value instead, use `return` rather than `print()`

```
def absolutevalue(num):
  if num > 0:
    print(num)
  elif num < 0:
    abs_value = num * -1
    print(abs_value)
  else:
    print("Absolute value is 0")
```